# How to keep only the first array of an array?

Tags: php

The title is a bit 'misleading, but the question is simple and I will try to explain what I'm trying to do. Typically to remove the indexes of an array I using unset, but in this case I have an array containing other arrays, each array is classified with an index. What I want to do is to keep only the first array and eliminate unset with everyone else, how?

**Example structure**

```
array(7) { 
           [0]=> array(14) { ... } 
           [1]=> array(14) { ... }
          }
```

I want keep only the array with 0 index, so the first array available. How do this?

Comment: `$keep=array_shift( $arr );` perhaps?

Comment: Uhm sound's good. I did not know this function, it appears to face for me. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reset` sets the pointer to the first item in an array and returns it:

```
$item = reset($array);
```

`$item` will contain the array found in the first index.

Comment: Yeah! Thank you, have a nice day :)